# NDK Debugging, can't set a breakpoint

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

**Use-case**

1. C++ code common to a Windows Phone & Android application
2. Windows Phone is compiled using Visual Studio
3. Android is compiled using Eclipse @ Ubuntu/Linux
4. Source-code is stored on the windows machine hard-drive
5. Source-code is shared with the Android/Linux machine using an SMB share

**Code is compiled successfully in the two environments**, however, on Eclipse/Linux a native break-point can't be set with: msg="No source file named %Some name%", This, having in mind that:

1. Binary is compiled having CFLAGS including "-UNDEBUG -g -ggdb" , "NDK_DEBUG := 1"
2. '*info sharedLibrary*' indicate that the symbols for the lib have been successfully loaded
3. '*info sources*' result a list of VALID file paths pointing into the SMB share

Why do I get the  "No source file named" GDB error?
How can I verify that GDB can access the SMB share where the sources reside ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: [SOLVED] In contrast with Windows, Linux FS is case-sensitive, this means that a folder named "JNI" is different than a folder named "jni", and these can co-exist under the same directory.

Debugging info directs to the "jni" folder ( and not to "JNI" ),
Renaming my "JNI" folder to "jni" resolved the problem, I am now able to debug Native code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrast with Windows, Linux FS is case-sensitive, this means that a folder named "JNI" is different than a folder named "jni", and these can co-exist under the same directory. Debugging info directs to the "jni" folder ( and not to "JNI" ), Renaming my "JNI" folder to "jni" resolved the problem, I am now able to debug Native code!